# Is the serverUrl returned to the SOAP login API predictive?

Tags: soap-api

I am using the SOAP API to retrieve data from a Salesforce Instance.

The URL for the login request to my instance is something like:

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0
```

The login request returns a serverUrl which is used in all subsequents SOAP requests for the session. The serverUrl is something like:

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0/00Db00000008aQk
```

I understand that this portion of the Url `/services/Soap/u/38.0/` reflects the version of the API and is constant.

Does the value following the API version, `00Db00000008aQk`, have any meaning and is it predictive?

Will `00Db00000008aQk` remain constant or is this a dynamic value?

Comment: That is the org id and will vary with the org. Also the API will vary based on org as well

Answer (score 0):

the last part of your URL is the [Org Id](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006019&type=1) which will be different between production and sandbox and also changes every time your sandbox is refreshed.

but when making the login api call you don't need to include the org id in the url. you can leave it up to the version number.

Production: https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/38.0/

Sandboxes : https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/38.0/

the portion after /services/soap will define which service you are using.

/c  - Enterprise

/u - partner

and the version number will define which api version (tied to the releases) you are using.

Also it seems you have enabled mydomain which has given your salesforce instance a custom domain

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce.com recommends that you use whatever the serverUrl is in the [LoginResponse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm) object you get back. Failure to use this property may result in things breaking later. While you can arguably predict what it is *today*, there's no guarantee it will be like that in the next release. As mentioned by others, 00DXXXXXXXXXXXX is an org ID, which will remain stable forever for your production org, and will change with each Sandbox refresh. However, there is absolutely no guarantee that this will be true in future releases, and should not be considered predictable.